# Problems with my Cydia repo

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, repository, cydia

I am hosting a personal repo for my friends. I am using the cyman script to generate and maintain the repo. I have my repo hosted at `http://184.95.54.221/` The problem is that on the iphone when you go into the repo you cannot see the packages and the packages cannot be found. However they are still "listed". You're welcome to install the repo to look.

Comment: You should mention how this relates to programming, or people will probably come and close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your repo has the file called packages.gz

You can create it using the command

```
dpkg-scanpackages -m . /dev/null >Packages
```

Comment: it does. I verified that it has all the files required and that they are all correct and up to date.

Comment: try running that command inside the folder that contains either the folder of the debs or the actual debs themselves

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Packages' file is invalid. Name, Author, Depiction, Icon - these fields has indentation at the beginning of a line. Remove it and Cydia will see your packages.